# How do I use the device's GPS only whenever there is no internet available?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-gps

Android is constantly changing. Currently, the `Fused Location API` is being used for location detection. But in my experience, without a Data connection, the GPS signal is not being found anymore.

How do I use the device's GPS only whenever there is no internet available?

Answer (score 0):

Fused location provider uses a hybrid way to find gps using a variety of sensors, WIFI/data and the actual GPS chipset.

It will find the location COARSE/FINE accuracy is up to your case. It will just take a while longer than with the internet connection. If indoors or in an isolated area, it may very well take over a minute or two. Sometimes if the data signals just don't reach the device, yes it can fail.

It does work without WIFI or DATA in most cases.

Comment: But it needs to connect to the play services, so it has to have internet. In my experience, before marshmallow the gps signal was found much quicker using the internal gps-sensor. Therefore it is delayed by firmware.

Comment: It will try to connect to internet using play services yes. The speed at which it is found really depends on the Chipset to be honest. I have seen varying results on different phones that i have tested on. But rather than using location manager, i would still advise using Fused services, it generally monitors GPS if any other app in the device is listening for it. So it is generally a good idea to rely on it

Comment: @Kushan Does that mean, it will try to connect but if it fails, it will still look for the location?

Comment: Yes... It will then try without internet using just the gps chipset